# DocuSign PHP Client doesn't allow listing template folders. Missing optional list query paramaters

Tags: php, docusignapi

According to the [DocuSign API Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Folders/Folders/list/#request)

`Folders::list` accepts optional query parameters but currently there is no way to include these using the *DocuSign PHP Client* since that method only accepts the [`account_id`](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/src/Api/FoldersApi.php#LC321).

I should be able to include `['template' => 'only']` somewhere to get a list of template folders.

Is there a way to do this I'm not seeing?

Example:

```
$folderApi = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\FoldersApi($apiClient);
$folders = $folderApi->list($accountId); //<-- DOESN'T ACCEPT ADDITIONAL ARGUMENTS FOR TEMPLATE
```

Comment: Can you please share your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Please use latest PHP client (version 4.0.0) https://packagist.org/packages/docusign/esign-client and see if this resolves your issue.